# Can't Update child components property in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, page-lifecycle, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have one functionality for filter data. when I enter some values in filter popup it showing result successfully. then I add those data in local storage (as I need to keep those data on back link) and I am redirecting to another page, when I press back button on current page and navigate to same filter component then I need to set filter components value from local storage but I got an error like this **"Cannot set property 'status' of undefined at SearchUserGridComponent.autoFillAdvanceSearch"** I am trying so hard in this issue please help. code is shown below.

```
**SearchUserGridComponent.ts**



@ViewChild('callDialog', { static: true }) callDialog: TemplateRef<any>;

openUserAdvancedSearchPopup() {
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.callDialog,{
          width: "80vw",
          maxWidth: "1366px",
          disableClose: true
        });
      }

**search-user-grid.component.html**

<ng-template #callDialog let-ref>
    <div *ngIf="design?.is_advanced_search_enabled" class="advanced-search" [ngClass]="{'show-advanced-search':showAdvancedSearch}">
        <advanced-user-search-component *ngIf="searchColumns?.length>0" [columns]="searchColumns" [dropDown]="dropDown"
            (getSearchedParams)="getSearchedParams($event)" (getSearchedTerms)="getSearchedTerms($event)"
            backgroundColor="rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.4)">
        </advanced-user-search-component>
    </div>
   </ng-template>

**advanced-user-search.component.ts**

search() {
        debugger
        let params = new HttpParams();
        if (this.status != null && this.status != "A") {
            if (this.status == "AC") {
                params = params.append('isActive', "" + true)
            }
            else if (this.status == "I") {
                params = params.append('isActive', "" + false)
            }

        }
        if (this.passwordComplexity != null && this.passwordComplexity != "A") {
            if (this.passwordComplexity == "D") {
                params = params.append('IsDefaultPolicy', "" + true)
            }
            else if (this.passwordComplexity == "S") {
                params = params.append('IsDefaultPolicy', "" + false)
            }
        }
        if (this.userLockedUnlocked != null && this.userLockedUnlocked != "A") {
            if (this.userLockedUnlocked == "U") {
                params = params.append('IsLocked', "" + false)
            }
            else if (this.userLockedUnlocked == "L") {
                params = params.append('IsLocked', "" + true)
            }
        }
        if (this.selectedEntity && this.selectedEntity.entityId) {
            params = params.append('entities', "" + this.selectedEntity.entityId)
        }
        if (this.selectedEntityType != null) {
            params = params.append('entityTypes', "" + this.selectedEntityType)
        }
        // console.log(this.selectedRoles)
        if (this.selectedRoles != null) {
            let roleString = "";
            this.selectedRoles.forEach(role => {
                roleString = roleString + "," + role
            })
            params = params.append('roles', "" + roleString)
        }
        if (this.selectedBranch && this.selectedBranch.branchid) {
            params = params.append('branchid', "" + parseInt(this.selectedBranch.branchid));
        }
        this.getSearchedParams.emit(params);
        this.dialog.closeAll();
    }
```

when user clicks back button these methods would be called on search-User-Grid.component.ts

```
**SearchUserGridComponent.ts**

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.isBack == "true" && this.design.screen_name == "searchUsers") {
            this.showAdvancedSearch = true;
            this.autoFillAdvanceSearch();
          
        }
}

 @ViewChild("advancedSearchComponent", { static: false }) advancedSearchComponent: AdvancedUserSearchComponent;

 autoFillAdvanceSearch() {
        let userSearchData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userSearchData"))
        if (userSearchData != null && userSearchData != undefined) {

            if (userSearchData["search"] == undefined || userSearchData["search"] == null) {
                this.searchTerm = "";
            }
            else {
                this.searchTerm = userSearchData["search"];
            }

            let status = userSearchData["isActive"];
            if (status == "true") { // Status
                this.advancedSearchComponent.status = "AC";
            }
            else if (status == "false") {
                this.advancedSearchComponent.status = "I";
//**Error throwing from here it tells "Cannot set property 'status' of undefined at SearchUserGridComponent.autoFillAdvanceSearch"**//
            }
            else {
                this.advancedSearchComponent.status = "A";
            }

            let IsDefaultPolicy = userSearchData["IsDefaultPolicy"];
            if (IsDefaultPolicy == "true") { // IsDefaultPolicy
                this.advancedSearchComponent.passwordComplexity = "D";
            }
            else if (IsDefaultPolicy == "false") {
                this.advancedSearchComponent.passwordComplexity = "S"
            }
            else {
                this.advancedSearchComponent.passwordComplexity = "A";
            }

            let IsLocked = userSearchData["IsLocked"];
            if (IsLocked == "true") { // IsLocked
                this.advancedSearchComponent.userLockedUnlocked = "L";
            }
            else if (IsLocked == "false") {
                this.advancedSearchComponent.userLockedUnlocked = "U"
            }
            else {
                this.advancedSearchComponent.userLockedUnlocked = "A";
            }



            let entityTypes = userSearchData["entityTypes"];
            if (entityTypes != undefined && entityTypes != null && entityTypes != "") {
                this.advancedSearchComponent.selectedEntityType = Number(entityTypes);
                this.advancedSearchComponent.populateEntity();

            }

            let entityId = userSearchData["entities"];
            if (entityId != undefined && entityId != null && entityId != "") {
                this.advancedSearchComponent.selectedEntity.entityId = Number(entityId);
                this.advancedSearchComponent.getSelectedEntity(this.advancedSearchComponent.selectedEntity);

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.advancedSearchComponent.selectedEntity.entityId = Number(entityId);
                    this.advancedSearchComponent.selectedEntity.name = this.advancedSearchComponent.entities.filter(entity => entity.entityId == Number(entityId))[0].name;
                }, 1000)
            }

            let roles = userSearchData["roles"];
            if (roles != undefined && roles != null && roles != "") {
                this.advancedSearchComponent.selectedRoles = roles.split(',').slice(1).map(i => Number(i));
            }

            let branchid = userSearchData["branchid"];
            if (branchid != undefined && branchid != null && branchid != "") {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.advancedSearchComponent.selectedBranch.branchid = Number(branchid);
                    this.advancedSearchComponent.selectedBranch.name = this.advancedSearchComponent.branches.filter(branch => branch.branchid == Number(branchid))[0].name;
                }, 1000)

            }

            
            let sortingEvent = JSON.parse(userSearchData["sortingEvent"]);
            if (sortingEvent != null && sortingEvent != '') {
                this.sort.direction = sortingEvent["direction"];
                this.sort.active = sortingEvent["active"];
            }


            setTimeout(() => {
                this.advancedSearchComponent.search()
            }, 1000)

            if (userSearchData["showAdvancedSearch"] == "true") {
                this.showAdvancedSearch = true
            }
            else {
                this.showAdvancedSearch = false
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that your `advancedSearchComponent` is not defined. It would mean that your `viewchild` cannot find any item with id `advancedSearchComponent`. So just add `#advancedSearchComponent` to your `<advanced-user-search-component></advanced-user-search-component>` and it should fix that issue.